# How to change width of TinyMCE source code view panel to 100%

Tags: jquery, css, tinymce

I am using TinyMCS for my editor, i want to change width of source code view of this editor to 100%. Is there any plugin for this goal or any CSS or jQuery solution.

I used following code for create my editor:

```
tinymce.init({
selector: ".tinymce",theme: "modern",height: 300,
content_css : '/fonts/Nassim.css, /css/public.css',
language: "fa_IR",
plugins: [
     "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
     "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
     "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager code"
       ],
toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
image_advtab: true ,

external_filemanager_path:"/assets/plugins/filemanager/",
filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/assets/plugins/tinymce/plugins/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting "code_dialog_width" configuration parameter to your window.innerWidth
( https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/code/#code_dialog_width )